# Windows 8 - Cannot use remote desktop over wireless connection

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, cisco-vpn-client

I'm running WIndows 8 Home and trying to connect to a Windows 7 machine (that I know to be properly configured) using Cisco vpn.

I have for the last 6 months been able to wirelessly connect without issue to my work pc over the Cisco vpn however from last weekend (7 days ago), I am now only able to connect using a wired connection; my pc is fully up to-date with no change to the operating system or network drivers in the last 7 days, this is true of my router.

Strangely, I can use my Windows 7 vm (on the Windows 8 machine) to connect which rules out everything and points it to being something within the way the Windows 8 machine is processing the rdp but I cannot work-out what.

Any ideas?

Spec:
Dell Inspiron 7720
Wireless - Intel Centrino 2230n
Wired - Realtek PCIe FE

Windows 8 64bit
Cisco VPN Client
Remote Desktop Protocol version 8

Comment: Did your work change any network configuration? They could limit the ability to vpn in over an unsecured network and your home computer isn't communicating the security properly.

Comment: No, no changes. I am actually connected at the moment using the Win 7 vm which leads me to there being something within Windows 8 that has decided to prevent access to remote desktops